# How to make half of the text inside of a div and the other half outside in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: Image here]

As you can see on the pic, I want the "h" to be on the blue div, and the "ello" to be on the white part of the picture. I tried to float the "h" to the right, and then add a ::after with the content "ello" but that didn't work. How would I go about doing this?

```css
.home-text-h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 30%;
 float: right;
 font-size: 40px;
}

.home-text-h1::after {
 content: "ello";
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left-margin">
    <h1 class="home-text-h1">h</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use ::first-letter

Comment: why not just write hello in your tag and put a span around the bit you want a different colour - would be much more accessible, especially if it is a h1

Comment: You don't have the blue background-color anywhere on in your posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign nagative margin to home-text-h1

```html
<div style="background:blue;width:200px;padding:20px;">
                <div className="left-margin" style="background:red;width:100px;">
                    <h1 className="home-text-h1" style="margin-left:-20px">hello</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: This is the only thing that actually worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical html5 solution with the use of the mark tag, however anything that displays inline will work, you can also make use of a span tag.

```html
  <h1 className="home-text-h1">H<mark style="background: red;">ello</mark></h1>
```

Or with span tag:

```html
      <h1 className="home-text-h1">H<span style="background: red;">ello</span></h1>
```

A more "elaborate" example:

```css
h1 {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:first-letter {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <h1 className="home-text-h1">H<span style="background: red;">ello</span></h1>
```

Simple example with ::first-letter (not recommended as support is not good atm)

```css
   h1 {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:first-letter {
  background: white !important;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: It's semantic correct to use mark tag for a part of word? Only my curiosity, i think at this solution but i have this doubt.

Comment: @Sfili_81 marked is used for marking, highlighting text, so it is the correct use since you're basically "highlighting" a part of that word.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp

Comment: But from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) (wich i prefer for documentation): Don't use <mark> for syntax highlighting purposes; instead, use the <span> element with appropriate CSS applied to it. This is where my doubt come from. :)

Comment: @Sfili_81 as I mentioned you can also use a span tag, updated the examples to include a span tag

Answer (score 1):

First mistake you did was using the wrong attribute. It should be `class` and not `className`. Second is assuming that ::after isn't part of the "parent" element, but if you float something, then the ::after will count as part of the floated element. So your original idea didn't work. I placed the ::after after the actual container div and translated it to be outside the container. See the code below:

```css
.left-margin {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #272343;
}

.left-margin::after {
    content: "ello";
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateX(100%); /* move element it's own size to the right */
}

.left-margin::after, /* style the after element just like the h1 */
.home-text-h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 0px; /* place to the right */
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="left-margin">
        <h1 class="home-text-h1">h</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below.
You can add another separate div in HTML. here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.home-text-h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
}
h1{
    display:inline;
    float: left;
}
.home-text-h1::after {
    content: "ello";
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div className="left-margin">
    <h1 className="home-text-h1">h</h1>
  </div>
  <div className="left-margin">
    <h1 className="home-text-h1">ello</h1>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.whiteDiv {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

.blueDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="blueDiv">
    <h1>h</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="whiteDiv">
    <h1>ello</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `:first-letter`.

```css
div {
  background: red;
}

div.container {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

h1::first-letter {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```